# If there is a prime in $(m^{1/2},m^{1/2}+m^{x/2})$ why is there another prime in $q\in(m^{1/2}-2m^{x/2},m^{1/2})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I can understand the next step of a proof:

Let it $x$ such that for every large enough $m$, there is a prime $p\in(m,m^{1/2}+m^{x/2}$). Then there is a prime $q$ such that $q\in(m^{1/2}-2m^{x/2},m^{1/2})$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The way its written, this seems frivolous since $2m^{x/2}>m^{1/2}$, because for $(m, m^{1/2}+m^{x/2})$ to be nonempty for all large $m$, you need $x\geq 2$. In other words there's always a prime $q\in(0,m^{1/2})$.

Comment: thanks too much, Now I see how easy it was